# Espacios en blanco en base de datos y en vista Javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql

Tengo una base de datos de libros en la cual en los campos de títulos algunos espacios es otro carácter por lo cual no lo identifica tal cual como espacio

Eso hace que en mi vista al querer listar los libros no me haga el salto de línea

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver algunos títulos no hacen el salto de línea porque los espacios como tal no son espacios.
Ya intenté en hacer un replace pero no identifica los espacios, tampoco con un .split().join() porque tampoco lo identifica

Aquí el ejemplo de unirlos con comas para comprobar que hace correctamente los métodos pero que no identifica los espacios y por lo tanto no lo hace
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna idea para solucionarlo? Vi que en la base de tatos borrando esos "espacios" y ponerle el espacio bien lo soluciona (cambiarlo manualmente). Pero son más de 6000 títulos, no me gustaría hacerlo manualmente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno hay varias formas de hacer esto lo mejor es normalizarlo y no hacerlo en cada consulta la razón es que generas mas carga al leer los datos

**ANTES DE HACER ESTO HAZ UNA COPIA DE LA BASE DE DATOS**

Como solucionarlo se me ocurren 2 formas

**1.** Opcion si es una tabla con un campo

```
update [nombre tabla] set [nombre del campo] = replace([nombre del campo],'[simbolo o caracter a remplazar]',CHAR(10) + CHAR(13));
```

**2.** Si es mas de una tabla que tiene este problema y hay varios campos

Haciendo un dump de la base de datos a un sql hacer el cambio con find and remplace de algún editor de texto y reimportar la base de datos

Dump

mysqldump -u root -p[contraseña] [nombre base de datos] > basededatos.sql

Restaurar la base de datos

mysql -u root -p[contraseña] [nombre base de datos] < basededatos.sql